# Access Magento Admin on Subdomain

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, nginx, htaccess

I have a running store on Magento 2 which has multiple websites that I can access in the front end without any problems, for example:

```
https://siteone.mymagestore.com
https://sitetwo.mymagestore.com
https://sitethree.mymagestore.com
.
.
.
```

But when I try to access the admin panel in the same way it redirects me to the main store URL, for example:

https://siteone.mymagestore.com/admin -> Redirects to https://www.mymagestore.com/admin

How can I allow accessing the Magento admin panel on URLs like https://siteone.mymagestore.com/admin as well?

I have tried many aspects to solve the problem but nothing seems to help. Any help on it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please check this https://gist.github.com/tegansnyder/65ba3396ec7cbf70bec9
 link it may help you.

Comment: Already tried, doesn't seems to help.

Comment: Hi, Anyone get a solution for this requirement? please share here

Comment: This seems not possible with Magento out of the box. I tried overriding several flows/functionalities in the core code as well, without any success.